# Prove $(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2 \ge 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)$ for $abc = 1$ ($a, b, c > 0$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc=1$. Does it then hold that $$(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2 \ge 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)$$

A lazy and non-rigorous computation suggests that, after substituting $c = \frac {1}{ab}$, the resulting function in $a,b$ is convex, and hence the local minimum at $a = b = 1$ is the global minimum and the inequality is true.

This problem came out of an amusing game I have been playing lately, in which I ask ChatGPT to make up Putnam problems which I then attempt (they are often hilariously false). The above question was one such problem which my basic knowledge of olympiad inequalities was unable to make much headway in either direction on (my ideas to use mean inequalities or symmetric polynomial inequalities failed, though I did not try Lagrange multipliers or similar methods). If the AI stole it from somewhere I would like to know.

Comment: Are you familiar with Vac's EV method?

Comment: No, please enlighten me

Comment: Read up on it. The implications of the theorem is that we just need to consider the case of $ a = b, c = 1/a^2$, so it becomes a single variable inequality (which you can then show is true).

Comment: I cannot find it on google, do you have a link?

Comment: Ah, it seems you perhaps meant to say Vasc's EV method.

Comment: Ah yes, was auto-corrected. It's the [Equal Variable method](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf)

Comment: I'm having trouble applying it. If I let $f(x) = x^6 - 3x^4 + \frac{2}{x^3}$, then $(a^3  +b^3 + c^3)^2 - 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4) = f(a) + f(b) + f(c)$ after noting $\frac{1}{a^3} = b^3c^3$, but $f$ doesn't seem to satisfy $f'(\frac 1 x)$ being strictly convex, its second derivative is negative near $1$.

Comment: You'd want to show that $( 2x^3 + \frac{1}{x^6} ) ^2 \geq 3(2x^4 + \frac{1}{ x^8} ).$

Comment: I actually can show that, my issue with the method is earlier. The theorem in the paper you linked has a condition which I don't think is met when I tried to apply it naively, namely the strict convexity of this $f'(\frac 1 x)$

Comment: Ah, I have understood the method a bit better now and think I see how to apply it. A better attempt to apply this is to let $x = a^3, y= b^3, z = c^3$, and then maximize $3(x^{4/3} + y^{4/3} + z^{4/3})$ subject to $x + y + z = u \ge 3$ and $xyz = 1$. Now the theorem applies as $4x^{-1/3}$ is convex, so this is indeed maximized for a given $u$ when $x = y = a^3, z = \frac {1}{a^6}$, and we are done. Thank you so much! I will hopefully write up the details later today as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a proof in Jan 10, 2023.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)^2 - 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)\\
 ={}& a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + 2a^3b^3 + 2b^3c^3 + 2c^3a^3 - 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)\\
 \ge{}& a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + (3a^2b^2 - 1) + (3b^2c^2 - 1) + (3c^2a^2 - 1)  - 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4) \tag{1}\\
 ={}& a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + 3a^2b^2 + 3b^2c^2 + 3c^2a^2 - 3a^4 - 3b^4 - 3c^4 - 3\\
 ={}& a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + 3a^2b^2 + 3b^2c^2 + 3c^2a^2 - 3a^4 - 3b^4 - 3c^4 - 3a^2b^2c^2\\
 ={}& (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 3)(a^4 + b^4 + c^4 -a^2b^2 - b^2c^2 - c^2a^2)\\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we use $2a^3b^3 - (3a^2b^2 - 1) = (2ab + 1)(ab - 1)^2 \ge 0$ in (1), and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge 3$ by AM-GM,
and $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 -a^2b^2 - b^2c^2 - c^2a^2 \ge 0$ (easy).

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if this inequality is true. As per Wolfram Alpha, it does not have a global minima.

Take $a = x/y, b = y/z$ and $c = z/x$. Then we want to show that

$$
\Big(\Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big)^3 + \Big(\frac{y}{z}\Big)^3 + \Big(\frac{z}{x}\Big)^3 \Big)^2 - 3\Big(\Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big)^4 + \Big(\frac{y}{z}\Big)^4 + \Big(\frac{z}{x}\Big)^4 \Big) \ge 0
$$

But [Wolfram Alpha says the expression on the left has no global minima](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize%20%28%28x%2Fy%29%5E3%20%2B%20%28y%2Fz%29%5E3%20%2B%20%28z%2Fx%29%5E3%29%5E2%20-%203%28%28x%2Fy%29%5E4%20%2B%20%28y%2Fz%29%5E4%20%2B%20%28z%2Fx%29%5E4%29%2C%20x%2Fy%20%3E%200%2C%20y%2Fz%20%3E%200%2C%20z%2Fx%20%3E%200). Further more even if we relax the condition that $a,b,c$ must be positive, [Wolfram Alpha still says that there is no global minima](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize%20%28%28x%2Fy%29%5E3%20%2B%20%28y%2Fz%29%5E3%20%2B%20%28z%2Fx%29%5E3%29%5E2%20-%203%28%28x%2Fy%29%5E4%20%2B%20%28y%2Fz%29%5E4%20%2B%20%28z%2Fx%29%5E4%29).

Comment: It is unsurprising that this function you've written (call it $g(x,y,z)$) has no global minima, as it is homogeneous in $x,y,z$, so $g(x,y,z) = g(\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z)$. Therefore I don't think this is much evidence either way.

Comment: @MatthewBolan Thats because $g(x,y,z)$ is the same as your original expression after we apply the transformation $a = x/y, b = y/z, c = z/x$. It satisfies all the conditions of your original expression

Comment: I agree it satisfies the conditions of the original expression. I do not agree that a global minima of the original function corresponds to a global minima of $g(x,y,z)$. For example the inequality $x^2 + y^2 \ge 2$ subject to $xy = 1$ is true by Cauchy Schwarz, but your method would look for a global minima of $\frac x y + \frac y x$, which does not exist as it is homogeneous.

Comment: @MatthewBolan Well your example above is incorrect. If $xy = 1$ then we can then $x^2 + y^2 \ge 1$ and the above substitution method shows the same. Substitute $x = p/q, y = q/p$ then we need to find the minima of $p^2/q^2 + q^2/p^2$ which is $2$ as seen here. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize+%28p%2Fq%29%5E2+%2B+%28q%2Fp%29%5E2

Comment: I agree I forgot the squares. That wolfram alpha link uses a weaker definition of global minima than I was - It finds minima along the lines $p = q$ and $p = -q$, and not at individual points. In your original link it seems to be looking for points which are local/global minima (and incorrectly reports single points with $x=y=z$ as local minima).

Comment: @MatthewBolan Not necessarily as here even unconditionally it does not report a local or a global minima. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize+%28%28x%2Fy%29%5E3+%2B+%28y%2Fz%29%5E3+%2B+%28z%2Fx%29%5E3%29%5E2+-+3%28%28x%2Fy%29%5E4+%2B+%28y%2Fz%29%5E4+%2B+%28z%2Fx%29%5E4%29

Comment: I remain unconvinced and do not trust Wolfram Alpha here as it is clearly using some numerical method and is incorrectly reporting the local minima at least sometimes, so I used Mathematica. I dehomogenized by letting y = 1 (so a global minima would actually be expected), and called Minimize[{((x)^3 + (1/z)^3 + (z/x)^3)^2 - 
   3*((x)^4 + (1/z)^4 + (z/x)^4), {x > 0, z > 0}}, {x, z}], which according to the documentation should find a global minima.  It eventually returned $x = 1, z = 1$ as a global minima, so the inequality should be true.

Comment: @MatthewBolan Wolfram Alpha actually runs on Mathematica under the hood so in all essence they are one and the same

Comment: I know this, however we want to call Minimize and let it run for a while, while I think wolfram alpha is calling NMinimize (perhaps after timing out a call to Minimize) and giving you misleading answers.